# How to remove all hyperlinks from a LibreOffice writer document ready for publishing?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, openoffice.org, auto-completion

I have a small book in LibreOffice writer format that I am preparing for self-publishing on Lulu. I have followed the instructions for pdf export that lulu have given for OpenOffice (given that LibreOffice was originally forked from OpenOffice and the pdf export dialogues still have the same tabs and much of the same options).

However my first attempt to purchase a proof copy ran into problems as the pdf apparently contained 'hyperlinks'.

So I went into the autocorrect options, deselected the two checkboxes for 'hyperlinks', so that it wouldn't create any more.

Then I selected the entire document, by pressing `Ctrl-A` and then right-clicked and selected `Remove hyperlink`. Theoretically this should have removed hyperlinks from the entire document.

However, when I exported this as a pdf and uploaded it to Lulu, again they refused to print it on the basis of an embedded hyperlink. Whilst they have kindly provided me with a 'fixed' version of the pdf, I would like to know how to find and remove the hyperlink from the original document, preferably without losing any formatting, so that I won't have the same problem with future revisions (especially given that this is still only the first proof reading edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the answer correctly, the issue is to locate hyperlinks in a big odt document quickly.

This can easily be done using the "Navigator" feature of LO Writer. It lists bookmarks, images, tables, hyperlinks, comments and so on. To open the Navigator, hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or select Menu `View` -> `Navigator`.

If there's a hyperlink in the current document, it will be listed under the `Hyperlinks` section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was precisely it. Apparently two of the hyperlinks weren't removed when I tried removing them when selecting all via `ctrl-A`. I didn't know how to find the ones that still had them. Now they've been safely removed.